# Is there a way to call or reference cucumber scenario from a step or step definition?

Tags: cucumber, reusability, scenarios

I have various env configurations (each one of them is setup via a particular scenario). I want to reference one or more env scenario in my feature tests. I cannot use background since for same test case I have to iterate through all or most of the environments.

If I could reference a scenario (not step, which I know is doable in cucumber) from another step or step definition that could solve my problem.

One way to solve this problem is to have data table or set of data tables for env setup and reference those tables (via key) to the current scenario. Defining the data in "fixtures" and defining the behavior in ruby. But by that way I will be bypassing the cucumber layer, which I want to avoid.

I feel cucumber has some short comings in case of scenario reuse. Scenario is collection of data and behavior, which we should be able to reuse.